# Installing pyflann through conda and importing on python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, flann

I would like to use the package pyflann on python 3.5 (Win-64)
I use the app spyder from Anaconda 3 to write and compile my scripts. 
I have installed the package pyflann using command prompt and conda. It seems that the installation was successful since when I type

```
conda list
```

in the command prompt, the list displayed includes

> > flann      1.8.3      3      ccordoba12

However, I am unable to `import flann` or `pyflann` into python.

```
import flann       or     import pyflann
```

yields :

> > no module named (flann or pyflann).

I have tried a few other approaches from recommendations on this site without success and resulting in similar failures outlined in other questions on the site. I could really use a concise step-by-step approach to successfully using pyflann on python 3.5 through spyder. Any thoughts or suggestions on completing the process I started through conda would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The conda package `flann` contains the library for `flann`.

The conda package `pyflann` contains the python bindings for this library.

Try the following:

```
(nasa) [rovers@mars ~]# conda install -c conda-forge pyflann
(nasa) [rovers@mars ~]# python -c 'import pyflann; print pyflann.__path__'
['/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyflann']
```

Comment: Nehal - thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the first lines returns : "Package not found" followed by " did you mean "pyflann:flann"? 
I tried with install flann which seemed to work, but then a message error appeared stating that "'Python': function cryptography_locking_cb() called but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter. Returning 0."
import pyflann results in module pyflann not found.

Comment: The package is not found because the pyflann package from conda-forge is not built for Windows. See https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyflann